# UrlFetch App and Google Sheets make post request

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

At column A i have barcodes like this BT025573,BT0255732,BT0255745...etc Does is possible to make button on the sheet so when i click the button to make request to this site http://www.kaex.mk/proverka.aspx  and to put the Barcode (BT025573) in input name txtKargoKod and the result to be sent back on column B for example? I read about UrlFetchApp but i'm not sure if is possible

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that without an API on the other end this is going to be extremely difficult if not impossible. To be able to do POST and GET requests from Google Sheets to this site you would need this site to have something to handle them. If you are the owner of it you could try and make a backend to handle them and then give it a go with the Google Sheets API.